# Why do duplicate bone names in seperate armatures cause problem when animating for one action

Tags: armature, bones

I have two armatures that have the same name for their root bone; ROOT. When I try to animate both armatures at the same time in Pose Mode, animating one ROOT bone of an armature will apply the same animation to the ROOT bone of the other armature. It doesn't look like it at first, but once you move the timeline cursor it then "processes" and the other bone will copy the translation of this bone. The quick and easy fix is simply to name them ROOT and ROOT.001. Is this intentional?

Comment: the action needs to be played in order to make the bone move, as long as the action is not played, the bone doesn't move. That said I don't understand what you mean by the way to fix is simply to rename, if you rename the bone, the bone that shared the same name in the other armature won't be animated anymore, as the keyframes of the action are attached to bones...

Comment: I meant that the issue specifically is that I cannot have two bones in two separate armatures be named the same, as if I animate one bone, the other bone will be animated as well, which I don't want

Comment: yes exactly, you can't, you need to either change the bone name, or duplicate the action so that it is not the same

Comment: Wait, so what if I have two seperate armatures that are humans. They both have a head so I would name the head bone like DEF_Head.001. Is the other armature just supposed to be called DEF_Head.002? What if I imported 2 characters that happen to have the same bone name? Would I have to make sure the characters don't have matching bones before I start animating? Also, thank you for replying

Comment: they can have the same bone name, what I say is that if you want to give the same action to armature2, you need to make sure that it has the same bone names as armature1, otherwise armature2 won't move

Comment: let's say you have armature1 with action1 and you've made action1 move a bone called headbone. If you give action1 to armature2, if action1 finds a bone called headbone in armature2, it will make it move, otherwise nothing will happen. But if 2 armatures have the same bone names but don't share the same action, they will move differently.